# Comparing incidence between groups over time

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, biostatistics

I have individual level whole population registry data where each observation describes a person `id` receiving a certain diagnosis `x` over a ten year period. The nature of `x` is such that each individual is very likely to receive it at least once each year and many do so more than once. For all intents and purposes you can view `x` as representing the common cold. I have very accurate age-specific population denominators.

I want calculate the incidence rate ratio for age-groups between time periods; years 1 - 5 and 6 - 10. I then intend to clarify any measured difference by performing a time-series regression. However, due to certain constraints I first have to calculate this overall comparison.

I am unsure of what method would be correct, e.g. to get reasonable confidence intervals. These are technically not cohorts as individuals enter and exit the age-groups over time. This is certainly not a case-control situation. There will even be situations where a certain individual will be represented in both time periods in the same age group such that the groups are not fully independent. I am unable to use survival analysis because individuals are able to receive the diagnosis multiple times.

i) Would it be within reason to calculate the incidence rate ratio by 'assuming' that this is a cohort over time scenario (i.e. number of diagnosis `x` over time at risk) using Wald confidence intervals and Mantel-Haenzel adjustment, i.e. `epi.2by2(data, method = "cohort.time")`from the [epiR](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/epiR/epiR.pdf) package?

ii) Is there a better approach that utilizes the fact that the underlying data is on the individual level?